# Connect my DB (separate server) with mysql-ssl

Tags: mysql, ssl

I want connect prestashop 1.6 to a DB separate server with mysql-ssl. 
Settings.inc.php don’t have any path options to SSL (ca.pem, client-cert.pem and client-key.pem).
Anyone have any ideas how do that?

Comment: Did you look at `mysqli_ssl_set` function in php? I think that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks you for your help, You are right I need mysqli_real_connect
I did some search in google and I need have something like  
Syntax:    
    
  
  
  mysqli_real_connect(connection,host,username,password,dbname,port,socket,flag);     
      Example    
<?php
$con=mysqli_init();
if (!$con)
  {
  die("mysqli_init failed");
  }

if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,"localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"))
  {
  die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>

Do you know where I need to put this and how, I’m note a programmer